# Click effect background is not working for buttons when we will do long press then drag in ios

Tags: ios

I am trying to give click effect for buttons when pressed.But when we pressed and then drag that click will be showing till next click.

Comment: put your code what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

If you create your button by passing system type in parameter then iOS gives the click effect.

```
let myButton = UIButton(type: .system)
```